# onPageStarted and onPageFinished don't work

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Here is my code snippet:

```
webView = (WebView) browserView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl(webUrl);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         if (url.contains("some_domain")) {
             webView.loadUrl(url);
             Toast.makeText(context, "Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else
             Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return true;
         }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Methods `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` are executed only the first time I click a link. Then, these methods don't work. What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: any error is thrown?

Comment: @Fahim nope. The log is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method to

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
```

Comment: But this method is not executed for some unknown reason after the page loads.